# Webapp not finding installed bower components

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, bower, eclipse-neon

I have a jersey-quickstart-webapp that i am developing in Eclipse Neon. I am trying to get bower up and running, and have installed bower as described by eclipse here: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article1.php

and as shown in the associated instruction video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PU8YoWNAkK0

That is:

1. I have installed node.js, npm, and bower
2. Ran Bower Init which created my bower.json file
3. Added angular as a dependency in my bower.json
4. Ran Bower install and installed angular
5. Updated my index.html to include the bower_components version of angular

My bower.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "pododdle",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.3"
  }
}
```

My bower_components directory has been successfully installed in my project with the following location containing the angular.min.js file: bower_components/angular/angular.min.js

I have changed the appropriate line in my index.html from:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

However, after the web-app is published to the server, when I try and load the application it fails to load in the browser and in the browser console displays a 404 error for the angular.min.js file, specifically pointing to the above src link in the index.html:

```
http://localhost:8080/pododdle/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js (index):12 GET 
http://localhost:8080/pododdle/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js localhost/:12
```

Am I missing a step in my bower installation? All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to this question asked here: [Can't Get Files Installed with Bower to Work in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564364/cant-get-files-installed-with-bower-to-work-in-eclipse)

It is solved by opening: Project -> Properties - > Deployment Assembly.

There you can see list of local resources which will be deployed by eclipse and their destinations. If you add your "bower_components" folder there and set its deploy path to "/bower" then you will be able to reference angularjs in your index.html file with the following line:

```
<script src="bower/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```